# Amplify: Failed to get profile: Profile configuration is missing for: undefined

Tags: amazon-iam, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I've some problems with the **amplify cli**:
I don't know if it's related to a recent cli update...

```
amplify init
? Do you want to use an existing environment? Yes
? Choose the environment you would like to use: staging
Using default provider  awscloudformation
? Select the authentication method you want to use: AWS profile
Failed to get profile: Profile configuration is missing for: undefined
```

---

```
amplify configure
Specify the AWS Region xxx
Specify the username of the new IAM user: xxx
Complete the user creation using the AWS console

Enter the access key of the newly created user:
 accessKeyId:  ********************
 secretAccessKey:  ****************************************

This would update/create the AWS Profile in your local machine
? Profile Name: default
Successfully set up the new user.
```

---

```
amplify push
? Select the authentication method you want to use: AWS profile
Failed to get profile: Profile configuration is missing for: undefined
```

---

```
amplify push
? Select the authentication method you want to use: Amplify Admin UI
```

OK! this time is working

```
UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS ...
UPDATE_FAILED      DeploymentBucket                         
AWS::S3::Bucket            Thu  API: s3:SetBucketEncryption Access Denied
(as admin)
```

How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution.
Inside the amplify/.config/local-aws-info.json
change

```
  "staging": {
    "configLevel": "amplifyAdmin"
  }
```

with

```
{
  "staging": {
    "configLevel": "project",
    "useProfile": true,
    "profileName": "default"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided solution solved my issue when trying to remove and environment via     `amplify env remove test-env`

I always got the following error:
`Failed to get profile credentials`
Amplify logs:
`amplify-provider-awscloudformation.system-config-manager.getProfileConfig([null])`

Changing configLevel from `amplifyAdmin` to `project` solved the error.
Thanks for sharing.